# Window size is different to mockup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have built an app with one of those non-standard shapes, so all the normal chrome is removed and everything consists of graphics that I designed in Adobe Fireworks.

When I run my app and compare the size of the window to the mockups that I made in FW, the app appears larger. The mockups I have are more than just mockups, they are identical to the app, I sliced these up into PNGs and used them to build with.

So the app looks exactly the same as the mockup, but it is slightly larger. Any ideas why and how to fix?

I have double checked that the width & height set in XAML are correct and same as the FW mockup, so no idea what's wrong with it.

Main reason I need to fix is that the images all appear slightly blurred, I suppose that's because the app is stretched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the DPI differences between WPF applications and standard images (web gifs etc).

Fireworks will by default create images at 72dpi, blend or WPF will scale images to **96dpi**.

In fireworks... when creating a new image (File > New...) set the resolution to **96** dpi (see screenshot)

The exported images will then scale correctly.

[image]

Ben

Comment: Ps: You can also change the DPI of an existing image by going to Modify > Canvas > Image Size...

Comment: You mean 96 dpi...if the machine is running at 96 dpi that is.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul: Thanks for the help, this sorted it all out.